# Hide income in Woocomercer

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm running a online business and soon I have to hire people to manage stock and products.

Is there a way to create an account for a employee that they not see the income panel or page ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

That should be relatively easy.

You can create a specific user role for your staff and then lock them out of the Orders page and any other admin page you deem confidential.

Answer (score -2):

This has two parts

1. You will have to contact a WC expert/support channel to ask if it is possible to be done with the the settings WC has.
2. It is possible to code such a thing, give different user role access to different data. (possible here is in the literal sense of the word. how easy/hard it is to do such a thing is again a question to the WC experts/support channels)